# Can a Google form be locked temporarily for maintenance?

Tags: google-forms

Can people be presented with a "form is down for maintenance" message just temporarily until the form is ready again?

Comment: YES. Please see this [test form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSebTvCXFQUmDUrYw0M1bb3-Zi8Zga5sxysmc4b_uJmgyC3ICg/viewform). If it meets your needs I can turn it to an answer explaining how to do the same.

Comment: Looks good to me! So how did you do it?

Comment: "_Looks good to me!_" Good.OK. But give me some time and I will do that after holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time Google Forms doesn't include a way to setup a custom message like "form is down for maintenance".

Considering the above, it could be a good idea to embed the form on a web page, maybe on Google Sites, so instead of sharing the form URL you share the web page URL and you could replace the embedded form with a message or other content.

Reference

- [View and manage form responses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en)